# Can it be learned which column caused the anomaly in detecting anomaly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to find anomalies in test data using semi-supervised machine learning. let's say we have data as follows. this data is unlabeled and this data is train data for anomaly detection. all values here are normal.(**does not contain abnormal value**)

```
column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7   column8   
10        15        35        20        41        78        32        45
74        41        45        41        42        32        31        41
15        10        12        11        12        13        14        12
```

and test data:

```
column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7   column8   
1800      15        35        20        41        78        32        45
74        41        45        41        42        32        31        41
15        10        12        11        12        13        14        12
```

the model will probably say there is an anomaly in the first row. Think of this in a multicolumn dataset. Is there any way I can get a printout like the following ?

**the abnormal condition is in the first row. and its value in the first row of the column named column1 is the cause of the abnormal condition.**

Comment: If you do a univariate (column-wise) anomaly detector, this comes out nauturally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need the model to do that, or you already have the algorithm to train. Anyway, if all values are numbers and you assume normal distribution you can use 3 sigma rule and in that case, everything in the mean +/- 3*sigma (standard deviation)  should be around 99.7% of your data. So if a number is out of that set it is probably abnormal. Another thing I don't get is your distinction between "line" and "row",I am assuming they are the same.

Here's what I came up with (I am new, so there are probably better ways):

```
mean = train_df.stack().mean()
std = train_df.stack().std()

inflim = mean  - 3*std
suplim = mean + 3*std

columns = test_df.columns.tolist()

    
ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n//10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4])
    
for column in columns:
    list1 = test_df[(test_df.idpozo < inflim ) | 
            (test_df.idpozo > suplim )].index.tolist()
    for item in list1:
        print("The abnormal condition is in the {} line,".format(ordinal(item)) + 
               "and its value in the {} row".format(ordinal(item)) + 
               "of the column named {}".format(column) +
               "is the cause of the abnormal condition.")
```